# How to return multiple values in python

Tags: python, web-crawler, httplib

I am working currently working on a spider; but I need to be able to call the Spider() function more than once to follow links, here is my code:

```
import httplib, sys, re

def spider(target, link):
        try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(target)
        conn.request("GET", "/")
        r2 = conn.getresponse()
        data = r2.read().split('\n')
        for x in data[:]:
            if link in x:
                a=''.join(re.findall("href=([^ >]+)",x))
                a=a.translate(None, '''"'"''')
                if a:
                    return a
    except:
        exit(0)

print spider("www.yahoo.com", "http://www.yahoo.com")
```

but I only get 1 link from the output, how can I make this all the links?

also how can I get the subsite from the links so the spider can follow them?

Comment: Hints: `yield`, tuples/lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably closer to what you're looking for

```
import httplib, sys, re

def spider(link, depth=0):
    if(depth > 2): return []

    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(link)
        conn.request("GET", "/")
        r2 = conn.getresponse()
        data = r2.read().split('\n')
        links = []
        for x in data[:]:
            if link in x:
                a=''.join(re.findall("href=([^ >]+)",x))
                a=a.translate(None, '"' + "'")
                if a:
                    links.append(a)

        # Recurse for each link
        for link in links:
            links += spider(link, (depth + 1))

        return links

    except:
        exit(1)

print spider("http://www.yahoo.com")
```

It's untested, but the basics are there.  Scrape all the links, then recursively crawl them.  The function returns a list of links on the page on each call.  And when a page is recursively crawled, those links that are returned by the recursive call are added to this list.  The code also has a max recursion depth so you don't go forever.

It's missing some obvious oversights, like cycle detection.

A few sidenotes, there are better ways to do some of this stuff.

For example, [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) can fetch webpages for you a lot easier than using httplib.

And [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) extracts links from web pages better than your regex + translate kluge.

Comment: I thought about that, but then wasn't sure what the expected return value was.  If you didn't want a top-level list of the links you found, then a deque would be more intuitive for sure.

Comment: great, just what I am looking for! great explanation and tips.

Comment: wow, using your tips I made an 8 line one! thank you so much :)

Comment: Thats great to hear.  BeautifulSoup is super helpful for situations like this and eliminates a lot of the ugliness that would otherwise be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Following doorknob's hint, if you just change the `return a` to `yield a`, your function becomes a [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators). Instead of calling it and getting back a result, you call it and get back an iterator—something you can loop over.

So, change your `if` block to this:

```
if link in x:
    a=''.join(re.findall("href=([^ >]+)",x))
    a=a.translate(None, '''"'"''')
    if a:
        yield a
```

Then change your `print` statement to this:

```
for a in spider("www.yahoo.com", "http://www.yahoo.com"):
    print a
```

And you're done.

However, I'm guessing you didn't really want to `join` up the `findall`; you wanted to loop over each "found" thing separately. How do you fix that? Easy, just loop around the `re.findall`, and `yield` once per loop:

```
if link in x:
    for a in re.findall("href=([^ >]+)",x)):
        a=a.translate(None, '''"'"''')
        if a:
            yield a
```

For a more detailed explanation of how generators and iterators work, see [this presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/).